# Read CSV file javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I have file.csv like this:

> Name,Gender   //header
>
> John,M
>
> Luke,M
>
> Jessy,F

I want to count total M and F with javascript so I have tried this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
        var F = 0;
        var M = 0;
    
    if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var table = $("<table />");
                var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = $("<tr />");
                    var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                    var gender = cells[1];
                    if (gender === "F"){
                            F++;
                     }else{
                            M++;
                     }
                    for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                        var cell = $("<td />");
                        cell.html(cells[j]);
                        row.append(cell);
                    }
                    table.append(row);
                }
                $("#dvCSV").html('');
                $("#dvCSV").append(table);
                window.alert(pos);
            }
            reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
        } 
     });
});
</script>
```

But **var F & M not increased** (just increased to 1 and didn't increase anymore) , can you help me to solve this problem? :(

Comment: so, only F is increased?

Comment: Do you have spaces after (and sometimes before) the comma like in the given example? If yes, you must take them into account.

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry updated guys :''

Comment: @Arnauld sorry updated guys :''

Comment: Another hypothesis is that the end of line consists of `\r\n` (CR+LF) rather than just `\n` (LF). In this case, what you get is `M\r` and `F\r`. Only the last row might be processed correctly if it's not followed by a carriage return.

Comment: @Arnauld Yes! you're right, it processed only the last row, what should I do :(

Comment: @jill182 log the processed file for us from javascript. `e.target.result`

Comment: You can try `e.target.result.split("\r\n")` and see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted has some missing brackets at the end so didn't run at first.
You should check and ignore empty lines, also check for male explicitly so that you don't count the header line.

For each line if gender is "M" of "F" in your code apparently there is an additional new line character at the end (character code 13), try gender.length and it will show 2. We can check by using gender.charAt(0) === 'F'(or 'M')

I modified the code and it works

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
            var F = 0;
            var M = 0;

            if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var table = $("<table />");
                        var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                            if (rows[i].trim() != '') {
                                var row = $("<tr />");
                                var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                                var gender = cells[1];
                                if (gender.trim().charAt(0) === "F") {
                                    F++;
                                } else if (gender.trim().charAt(0) === "M") {
                                    M++;
                                }
                                for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                                    var cell = $("<td />");
                                    cell.html(cells[j]);
                                    row.append(cell);
                                }
                                table.append(row);
                            }
                        }
                        $("#dvCSV").html('');
                        $("#dvCSV").append(table);
                        window.alert("F: " + F + ", M:" + M);
                    }
                    reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
    <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
</body>
</html>
```